# Savitzky-Golay (aka Hodrick–Prescot or Whittaker-Henderson) vs. Kernel

Tags: kernel-smoothing, smoothing, filter

Is there a clear analytic link from Kernel smoothing, particularly the Nadaraya–Watson estimator, (S-G, H-P, or W-H) smoothing filter?

The "filter" is called by different names in different fields including [analytic chemists & engineers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter), [economists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodrick%E2%80%93Prescott_filter), [actuaries](http://www.nber.org/chapters/c9366.pdf), and  the [statisticians](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205955/aic-on-savitzky-golay-width) (who tend to know several variants).

When I say "kernel method"for smoothing I am referring to an approach like this ([link](http://www.lancs.ac.uk/~struijke/density/kernel.html)), or possibly this ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression#Nadaraya.E2.80.93Watson_kernel_regression)).  I give an example in code below as well.  A Gaussian kernel is a variation on the Normal probability density, which by definition is non-negative.  The Epanechnikov and Uniform estimators are defined as piece-wise but share this constraint.

The "filter", like a kernel based smoother, makes a weighted sum of a window of points around the point of interest.  Unlike the smoother, the "filter" has negative valued coefficients.

How do I relate the negative weights in the "filter" with a kernel approach?  Is there a connection between the two?  Are they fundamentally incompatible?  How would I make a more robust Gaussian kernel smoother that has negative weights.

What I mean is this:
The coefficients for the [5-element quadratic smoothing filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter#Tables_of_selected_convolution_coefficients) are "-3, 12,17,12,and -3" with a normalization constant of 35.  The absolute values sum to 41.  This means ~15% of weight is negative. Is there a derivation from good solid first principles that gives a Normal Kernel smooth with similarly valued coefficients?

For example, let's say that I want estimate y_true from y_meas as given by the following.

```
set.seed(231529)

#create data
N <- 200
t <- seq(from=1,to=7*pi,length.out = N)
y_true <-  0.23*sin(1.5*t) - 0.5*cos(0.2*t+0.9)

#corrupt with noise
epsilon <- +runif(n = N,min=-0.1,max = 0.1)
y_meas <- y_true + epsilon

#plot it
plot(t,y_meas, xlab = "t", ylab="y")
lines(t,y_true,col="Green",lwd=2)
```

I can do this with Savitzky-Golay as follows:

```
#Savitzy-Golay
library(pracma)
y_sg <- savgol(y_meas,   #my data
               fl = 17,
               dorder=0, # snoothing
               forder=3)  # quadratic

lines(t,y_sg,col="Red")
```

While the Kernel methods are a way to approximate a probability density function there is this:
$$ \mu = \frac{\int x\cdot p\left(x\right) } {\int p \left(x\right) } $$
or in a discrete case
$$ \mu = \frac{\Sigma x\cdot p\left(x\right) } {\Sigma p\left(x\right) } $$
and so it can make a clean weighted windowed mean for non-uniformly distributed data.

```
#Kernel
y_k <- numeric(length = length(t) )
for (i in 9:(N-8)){

     xi <- t[(i-8):(i+8)]-t[i]; #domain
     yi <- y_meas[(i-8):(i+8)]; #range

     temp <- density(xi, #the window
                     bw = "sj",
                     kernel = "gaussian")

     #evaluate at our points - 
     w <- interp1(x=temp$x,y=temp$y,xi=xi)

     #normalize
     w <- w/sum(w)

     #find mean
     y_k[i] <- sum(w*yi)
}

lines(t,y_k,col="Blue",lwd=3)
```

For the same input data, the SG, using "eyeball norm", seems to do better.
Here is my plot.

[image]

The difference between the two is that SG (or such) is robust (negative coefficients) in a way that the classic Gaussian Kernel is not, unless there is a good reason to adjust the weights. Because it has a window, the N-W estimator is tending to regress toward the mean and so it overshoots the valleys and undershoots the peaks.

I appreciate the responses so far, and will go dig through them.  Thanks.

Comment: is "(link)" supposed to be a hyperlink?

Comment: The Whittaker-Henderson (etc) filters are all (discrete) *smoothing splines*, which are approached as distinct from kernel methods. However, they are certainly related to them; most obviously both are linear smoothers (i.e. can be written in the form $\hat{y}=Sy$). 
However, the connections run deeper. In particular you may want to investigate the the connections between various forms of splines and kernel smoothing, including *spline kernels*. e.g. see [here](http://www.bauer.uh.edu/rsusmel/phd/ec1-27.pdf), p39-40. (I *think* Härdle discusses that connection in *Smoothing techniques*.)

Comment: Indeed, (though less directly related) you might get something out of a look at the discussion in Pearce and Wand "*Penalized Splines and Reproducing Kernel Methods*" which discusses the connections between those (particular) spline and kernel methods.

Comment: In statistics does "kernel smoothing", if unqualified, generally refer to 0-th order moving least squares (piecewise constant, but with kernel weight)?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 often but not always. (If I understand you right that would usually be called [Nadaraya-Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression#Nadaraya.E2.80.93Watson_kernel_regression))

Comment: @Glen_b thank you for clarifying. According to Wikipedia, Nadaraya–Watson preceded by a year my least favorite variant: The "singular kernel" bastardization known as [IDW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting#Historical_Reference) which is still common in GIS software!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Savitzky-Golay filters are used to estimate smoothed values for a function and its derivatives, given $(x,f[x])$ pairs. Kernel Density Estimates are used to estimate smoothed values for a probability density function $p[x]$, given a sample of $x$ points.

I am not sure if this answers your question, but [moving least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_least_squares) is a generalization of Savitzky-Golay that uses an arbitrary kernel to weight the points. Savitzky-Golay filtering corresponds to the case of a uniform ("box") kernel, when the function $f[x]$ is sampled on a uniform $x$ grid.

Now in terms of smoothing, that can actually be an issue with higher-order Savitzky-Golay filters (i.e. [Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon)). In general if some kernel/filter has negative weights, then it can easily result in *roughening* of the input signal. The simplest example are derivative filters, but even [resampling kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts#Related_phenomena) can have these effects. In statistics typically a kernel will be non-negative, so these image processing "interpolation kernels" (e.g. [Lanczos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling#Lanczos_kernel)) are really a different beast.