# Savitzky-Golay with switching between scales based on slope

Tags: smoothing, filter

I am having fun with Savitzky-Golay ([aka H-P, W-H](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231529/savitzky-golay-aka-hodrick-prescot-or-whittaker-henderson-vs-kernel)) and I am bumping into limits of the filter.  It makes me [want a better filter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6uEMOeDZsA).

Is there a filter that adjusts filter order based on "slope" but that also, like Savitzky-Golay filter, has forms that lead cleanly to nice estimates of derivatives for the data?

It sounds like a contradiction: using slope to control knobs in estimating slope.  My hope is that it has at some point sounded like a mathematically interesting contradiction, and that someone found a reasonable solution for it.

Here is my pain (see images):

1. when the slope is low, the filter doesn't remove the effects of
   discretization.
2. if the window is any wider then the filter doesn't handle periods of
   oscillation.
3. if the order is lower, the linear area is handled well but the
   sinusoidal loses amplitude
4. when the order is higher the filter doesn't remove the effects of
   discretization

Slow slope with high order filter (notes Gibbs effect at plateau edges: filter adds noise):
[image]

Sinusoidal with high order filter:
[image]

Slow slope with low order filter (no ringing):
[image]

Sinusoidal area with low order filter (loses signal):
[image]